# Count occurences of percentage drop between consecutive points in a moving time window

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, promql, prometheus-operator

I want to alert in prometheus based on a rule which in simple English would read something like

```
alert if metric X has dropped once by 5% in the last 5 minutes.
```

The requirement to satisfy this rule is to measure drops in consecutive data points which come in 1 minute intervals, and if the drop in any of the data points is more than or equal to 5% we send an alert.

I am using a combination of different recording rules to achieve this. The algorithm I am going for is as follows

```
# First group of rules, runs every 1 minute
# Recording rule which measures the percentage drop between consecutive points
((idelta(metricX{job="A"}[2m]) / (metricX{job="A"} offset 1m)) * 100)

# Recording rule which generate a time series of 1 if percent drop is >= X% or 0 otherwise
<insert expression here>

# Second group of rules begins which runs every 5 minutes
# Alert rule which reads and sums the timeseries of 1's and 0's over the last 5 minutes and alerts if sum is greater than 0
sum_over_time(timeseries_1_0[5m]) > 0
```

How do I write the second recording rule? I have experimented with clamp_max/min. But I dont think that's what I want. What would help me is an if/else construct in promQL. Having no prior experience in timeseries querying is not helping either. Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
record: metricX:idelta_ratio
expr: ((idelta(metricX{job="A"}[2m]) / (metricX{job="A"} offset 1m)) * 100)

record: metricX:idelta_ratio_le-5
expr: metricX:idelta_ratio <= bool -5

alert: MetricXDroppedBy5Percent
expr: sum_over_time(metricX:idelta_ratio_le-5[5m]) > 0
...
```

Do note however that Prometheus does not guarantee that your metric will be collected exactly once a minute. Or your rules evaluated exactly once a minute. And that you are hardcoding the `1m` and `2m` ranges in your rules, which may misbehave in interesting ways if your scrape interval ever changes.

Comment: What happens if `(metricX{job="A"} offset 1m)` falls to zero?  Is there a divide by zero error?

Comment: There are no errors in PromQL. You'll simply get a `NaN` ("not a number") sample, for which the `<= bool -5` comparison will return `0` (i.e. "false").